# Is there an effective iron farm

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I don't want to spend 100 years mining but I want [Protection](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Protection) 4, [Sharpness](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sharpness) 5, [Fire Aspect](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fire_Aspect) 2, and [Looting](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Looting) 3
I already have 120 levels but I need iron (I have anvil and chest full of  [Protection](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Protection) 2, and [Sharpness](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sharpness) 3, [Looting](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Looting) 1. But no [Fire Aspect](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fire_Aspect)).
I have tried strip mining but I don't know what level iron is most common at.

Comment: Why you downvote me I have tried searching it up

Comment: What is the question here?
I just googled "iron most common minecraft" and the very first result tells you what levels iron is most common at. If people think you didn't bother searching it up, they have pretty good reasons to think that.

Comment: i dont want to mine though i want an afk farm

Comment: You can always enable cheat mode and give yourself whatever resources you need.

Comment: I DON"T CHEAT!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way, I’ll link a YouTube video to it.  This takes a lot of work, but it’s worth it. You’re going to need a lot obsidian, and if didn’t mention, also endless gold.

Comment: Thanks for the vid

Comment: I tried it out it works but the gold is very slow almost not worth the obby